# Run homebrew package from Swift Command Line Tool

Tags: swift, macos

I'm developing a macOS Command Line Tool target with Swift for my app.
With this target, I want to execute a Kotlin command (installed with homebrew).

Here's the Kotlin command:

```
kotlinc -script ./kotlin_file.kts
```

When I launch this Kotlin command from my terminal, there is no issue at all.

But when I run the Command Line target from Xcode, I get an error (different error depending on the method used, cf below).

I've tried multiple methods :

### Method 1

```
let test = execute1("kotlinc",
                    args: ["-script", "./kotlin_file.kts")
```

```
    private func execute1(command: String, args: [String] = []) -> String {
        let proc = Process()
        proc.launchPath = command
        proc.arguments = args

        let pipe = Pipe()
        proc.standardOutput = pipe

        proc.launch()

        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    }
```

Error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'launch path not accessible'
```

### Method 2

```
let test = execute2("kotlinc",
                    args: ["-script", "./kotlin_file.kts")
```

```
    private func execute2(_ path: String, args: [String] = []) {
        let process = Process()
        process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        process.arguments = args

        let outputPipe = Pipe()
        process.standardOutput = outputPipe

        try? process.run()

        let output = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let str = String(decoding: output, as: UTF8.self)
        print(str)
    }
```

Here with `Method 2` it stays stuck at `readDataToEndOfFile`.

### Method 3

I've put the Kotlin command inside a `script.sh` file and executed this shell file from the target, but it get this error :

```
kotlinc: command not found
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found multiple solutions :

### Solution 1 : Adding $PATH to env variables

Edit Scheme > Arguments > Environment Variables : Add `PATH` and set its value to `${PATH}`

### Solution 2 : Add Homebrew path to env variables

Edit Scheme > Arguments > Environment Variables : Add `PATH` and set its value to `PATH=${PATH}:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin`

### Solution 2 : Launch in terminal

Edit Scheme > Options : Set `Console` to `Use Terminal` . But I found this option very buggy with random errors.